# How to add Product Filter in pos.order model in Odoo 12

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

i want to add a filter name "product" as exactly the default filter in product model.
i have given a picture of the filter which i want[the filter which is in add custom filter]. any help will be appreciated.[image: the filter which is in add custom filter]

Comment: You can add the filter to your search record in the relevant view `.xml` file: 

    <filter string="Product Filter" name="my_product_filter" domain="[('product','=','your_parameter_here')]"/>

Include your .xml file that contains the search record and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: can you say me where is that code in core files
after selecting product in the dropdown list of custum filter there is another drop down list whis is contans,doesnot contain, equal to, notequal to
i need that functionalities also

Comment: I wouldn't recommend amending the core code since you'll lose it whenever it updates. You can create your own module and inherit the core module to override it. Take a look at Odoo's documentation or Odoo-mates on YouTube.

Comment: yeah bro i am doing it in my custom module but i need to get the reference since i want the default functionality i need that code from core..... no worries if it will be changed after updates i need the functionality which is in this update.... but i cannot get that code

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a tonne of code here, I'll post it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding a new custom filter you should inherit the search view of the action like below:

```
    <record id="pos_order_view_search_inherit_product_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">pos.order.search.inherit.product.filter</field>
        <field name="model">pos.order</field>
        <field name="mode">primary</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="view_pos_order_search"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//search" position="inside">
                <field name="lines" string="Product" filter_domain="[('lines.product_id', 'ilike', self)]"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This will add the option to search by product name in the search bar.

You can create a custom addon to do this, or just create a view from the backend  (Settings/Technical/Views menu).

Comment: bro in this you are adding a search catagory for product... its not the same as filter of product which is in custum filter dropdown...
yes i have to inherit search view to add a custom filter but i am unable to get the code of the custom product filter .....

the code you just shared is for the search not to add a filter bro

Comment: @SidharthPanda Yes, That's the only way you can give the option of searching by product, without editing the structure of pos.order model. I considered that the goal is to give the user the option to search by product. But if it is important to you to add it only in the custom filter section you have to add a field (maybe computed field that gets the products from the lines) to the pos.order model, Since the custom filter section only lists the fields of that model. You cannot add anything there unless you add a field to that model.

Comment: Also if you take a look at the sale orders menu (sale.order model) this is how Odoo itself enabled the option of searching for orders by product. Unless you have a good reason for yourself to enable that option through custom search section instead of the search bar options.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, you can access that view's source code in `odoo`>`addons`>`purchase`>`views`>`purchase_views.xml`

```
   <record id="view_purchase_order_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">request.quotation.select</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Purchase Order">
                <field name="name" string="Order"
                    filter_domain="['|', '|', ('name', 'ilike', self), ('partner_ref', 'ilike', self), ('partner_id', 'child_of', self)]"/>
                <field name="partner_id" operator="child_of"/>
                <field name="user_id"/>
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <filter name="my_purchases" string="My Purchases" domain="[('user_id', '=', uid)]"/>
                <filter string="Starred" name="starred" domain="[('priority', '=', '1')]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter name="draft" string="RFQs" domain="[('state', 'in', ('draft', 'sent', 'to approve'))]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter name="approved" string="Purchase Orders" domain="[('state', 'in', ('purchase', 'done'))]"/>
                <filter name="to_approve" string="To Approve" domain="[('state', '=', 'to approve')]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter name="order_date" string="Order Date" date="date_order"/>
                <filter name="draft_rfqs" string="Draft RFQs" domain="[('state', '=', 'draft')]"/>
                <filter name="waiting_rfqs" string="Waiting RFQs" domain="[('state', '=', 'sent'), ('date_order', '&gt;=', datetime.datetime.now())]"/>
                <filter name="late_rfqs" string="Late RFQs" domain="[('state', 'in', ['draft', 'sent', 'to approve']),('date_order', '&lt;', datetime.datetime.now())]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter invisible="1" string="Late Activities" name="activities_overdue"
                    domain="[('activity_ids.date_deadline', '&lt;', context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"
                    help="Show all records which has next action date is before today"/>
                <filter invisible="1" string="Today Activities" name="activities_today"
                    domain="[('activity_ids.date_deadline', '=', context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"/>
                <filter invisible="1" string="Future Activities" name="activities_upcoming_all"
                    domain="[('activity_ids.date_deadline', '&gt;', context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter string="Warnings" name="activities_exception"
                    domain="[('activity_exception_decoration', '!=', False)]"/>
                <group expand="0" string="Group By">
                    <filter string="Vendor" name="vendor" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'partner_id'}"/>
                    <filter string="Purchase Representative" name="representative" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'user_id'}"/>
                    <filter string="Order Date" name="order_date" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'date_order'}"/>
                </group>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: bro in this search filter as you can see there is no "product" filter.
the filter i am talking about is in the add custom filter drop down. i want that exact filter